# How to get the appsetting as an object in the ConfigureServices method of the startup.cs file and pass that to another service being added right after

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to load up a custom class in my aspnetcore startup that I want to be able to use through the lifetime of the application. This custom class needs some object which is based on data in the appsettings.json file.

I am using aspnetcore webapi 3.1 and I have currently this setup in my startup.cs class `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method,  which works:

```
 services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
 var _appConfig = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
 services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IMyCustomClasses), new MyCustomClass(_appConfig.Somevalue)));
```

In my controller, I got this constructor:

```
public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> config, IMyCustomClasses mc)
{
   _config = config; 
   _mc = mc;
}
```

While all of this works and I can get the instantiated custom class `MyCustomClass` along with an instantiated AppSettings class in my `HomeController`, I want to know if there is a way I can avoid using this line:

```
var _appConfig = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
```

to setup `MyCustomClass` on the line after it and somehow get it directly from the line before, which is:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

Any tips, ideas?

Comment: It is correct to read the value from appsettings through IConfigurations and IOptions extension. What is your specific problem now?

Comment: There is no problem. It works the way I have it above. I want to know if there is a way I can avoid using this line: `var _appConfig = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();` and use the services object in the line before it. more context in the questions above.